# Ambiguity of "I'm contacting you as <role>"

Tags: ambiguity

Yesterday I had to write an email to my organization's (say) Chief Poodle Liaison. There are many Chief Liaisons for various breeds, but only one responsible for poodles. And the given person has a different job title and potentially many other minor roles, one of which is being the Chief Poodle Liaison.

I started my email with "I'm contacting you as the Chief Poodle Liaison", to highlight that the reason why I was writing my email was due to this minor role of theirs and not something else (I'd never contacted them before, and the email was poodle-related). I wondered about this phrasing, because I could also read it as *me* being the CPL in the situation (in fact out of context I'd be more likely to read this sentence with this interpretation). I sent the email anyway, because we're both non-native English speakers, and it was clear from context what I'd meant even if my usage was incorrect.

Is this phrasing indeed ambiguous, allowing the role to refer to either the speaker or the addressee? (I understand that in practice this shouldn't be an issue, because context is always there to pin down the meaning.)

If it's unambiguous, which case (speaker has the role versus addressee has the role) does it apply to and how can I phrase the other case?

Comment: Surely you mean "Or if it *is* [ambiguous], how can I phrase . . . unambiguously?"

Comment: @BrianDonovan thank you, but no. I figured the two cases are _"yeah, it's ambiguous [but no worries because context is always there]"_ or _"it's unambiguous and I probably used it wrong, missing 50% of the cases"_. I'll try to clarify my post.

Comment: My suggestion would be to pack more of the meat of your message into your opening. You need not tell this CPL person, "I'm contacting you," for that much is obvious if your addressee reads this e-mail at all. If you are asking CPL to rescind new poodle-trimming guidelines, you could start with something like "Could you please, in your capacity as CPL, consider rescinding the new poodle-trimming guidelines?"

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, just insert ***I am*** or ***you are*** between ***as*** and ***<role>***.

Comment: Thanks for the dupe @FumbleFingers. I can't put my finger on why, but keeping the prepositional phrase (huh!) with "your capacity as <role>" sounds closer to me.

Comment: Well, obviously *...in **your / my capacity** as <role>* avoids any ambiguity. But then you wouldn't have a question to ask anyway! Whatever - I'm not sure what you mean by "sounds closer to me", but the "default parsing" for such constructions is to assume the ambiguous element attaches to the ***nearest credible referent*** (nearest ***preceding*** credible referent if a ***following*** referent is equally close). But That's just a default starting position. In practice we normally pay a lot of attention to the semantics, and choose the interpretation that makes most sense.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @FumbleFingers. By "sounds closer to me" I just meant that of the two suggested options it sounds better to me. But since this is very subjective and related to how I use English, I didn't want to use an absolute term like "sounds more natural to me". I merely meant that I'll be more likely to use the "your capacity" alternative, because that feels like it better matches the way I was going to express myself.

Comment: In practice it's hard to see how there could be ambiguity with your example *from the addressee's perspective*, since he probably knows perfectly well which of *he himself* and the *writer* can most naturally assume the specified <role> in the current context. There's only scope for ambiguity with *us*, when we're *reading* this interaction between two people we don't actually know much about!

Comment: I'm with @FumbleFingers, what specialist would not know their own role?

Comment: @YosefBaskin the point is that the person has 5 different minor roles, and I want to make it clear in what capacity they are being contacted. Writing to the CEO with "as the CEO" would indeed be silly.

Comment: No, including their role makes sense, but does not introduce the confusion of who has that role. As @psmears says, "absent any context" and here there is context. Otherwise, indeed we'd have _Who's on first?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes it is ambiguous; as you suspect (absent any context) it could refer to either you or your correspondent being the Chief Poodle Liaison; a brief [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%27m+writing+to+you+as%22) turns up many examples of both meanings. (Generally confusion does not arise, since in the vast majority of cases both parties know which of them is the Chief Poodle liaison.)
2. One good way of making it unambiguous would be to write

> I'm writing to you in (your/my) [capacity](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/capacity) as ...

Comment: Thank you, the same query proved too difficult for duckduckgo and I didn't think to check google :) And thanks for the concise disambiguation, sounds great.

Answer (score 1):

> "I'm contacting you as the Chief Poodle Liaison"

better

"I'm contacting you in your capacity of the Chief Poodle Liaison"